# Decompress .gz file from Azure blob in r

Tags: r, azure-storage, gzip

I want to read a .csv.gz from a Azure blob container, but I am struggling with the .gz format. When I download the file local and then read it in R with readr it works fine. But when I try to read it from Azure the file isn't read propperly. It seems that the file is not decompressed. This is the code I used to read the file local (also read_csv2 works fine):

```
df<-read_delim("filename.csv.gz", delim=";",col_names=c('epoch','SegmentID','TT','Speed','LoS','Coverage'),
                    col_types=cols(epoch = col_integer(),SegmentID = col_integer(),TT = col_integer(),Speed = col_integer(),LoS = col_integer(),Coverage = col_integer()))
```

And this is what I try to do to reach the file from Azure:

```
blob_urls_with_sas<-paste("https://name.blob.core.windows.net","/container/filename.csv.gz",
                          sas_token, sep="")
dfAzure<-read_delim(blob_urls_with_sas,delim=";",
col_names=c('epoch','SegmentID','TT','Speed','LoS','Coverage'),
                col_types=cols(epoch = col_integer(),SegmentID = col_integer(),TT = col_integer(),
                               Speed = col_integer(),LoS = col_integer(),Coverage =col_integer()))
```

or from the AzureStor package

```
test <- storage_read_delim(cont, "filename.csv.gz",delim=";",
col_names=c('epoch','SegmentID','TT','Speed','LoS','Coverage'),                           col_types=cols(epoch = col_integer(),SegmentID = col_integer(),TT = col_integer(),
                       Speed = col_integer(),LoS = col_integer(),Coverage = col_integer()))
```

Comment: use ``fread()``?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use `fread()` from data.table which naturally handles `.gz` files. Make sure you install `R.utils` first.